# Whether we should keep the tenses in harmony in the given context

Tags: tense

> I sent him a text today morning asking him whether he **can/could** over to my place today evening.

Are both options grammatically correct?
Can *can* or *could* either be used in this context, since the person the speaker sent the text to hasn't responded yet, and alongside that, it's not evening time yet?

Just like:

> I was thinking what **will/would** happen tomorrow.

The same goes for this one, it's not tomorrow yet, so I could just mix the tenses and it'd still be grammatically correct, right?

Comment: I think you mean: "I sent him a text *this* morning asking him whether he **can** / **could** *come* over to my place *this* evening".  Either is correct.

Comment: Both are grammatically correct, as long as we overlook the expressions "today evening" and "today morning", which are expressed as "this evening" and "this morning", respectively, in English.

Comment: Both the sentences in both the cases are right, right? @P.E.Dant

Comment: Yes, they are grammatically correct. The difference between _can_ and _could_ is subtle here, but not meaningful in the context. (The time of day doesn't make any difference.)